# Python Way - Processing multiple files & add the sum of all the results in Parallel

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have a list of 500 json  files. Contents of the files are as follows
`{'minute': '2022-11-16T02:29:00.000+00:00', 'mycount': [[0, 0], [1, 32], [2, 3456], [3, 446], [4, 534534], [5, 474], [6, 448], [7, 529], [8, 507], [9, 515], [10, 477], [11, 486], [12, 491], [13, 474], [14, 528], [15, 23]]}`

I want to achieve the following using parallel processing ( may be processing 100 files in parallel)

- For each file find the sum of second element of each element of mycount ( 0 + 32 +3456 +446+534534..]. Lets call it sum1
- calculate sum1 for all the files and return total sum = sum1 + sum2+ sum3...
  How can I achieve this using mutithreading in python?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind of using multiprocessing instead of multithreading, you can adopt [`multiprocessing` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) decoder to parse the content of your files:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import json

# Other libraries
import os
import warnings


def compute_file_sum(f):
    """Compute the sum for a file"""
    try:
        # Read the whole content
        with open(f, 'r') as ff:
            file_content = ff.readlines()

        # Load as a JSON (mind the change of ' into ")
        file_content = json.loads('\n'.join(file_content).replace("'", '"'))

        # Compute the sum of second items of each element in 'mycount'
        return sum(
            c[1] for c in file_content['mycount']
        )
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exceptions
        warnings.warn(f"Issues with file {f}, {str(e)}")
        return 0

def get_filepaths(root_dir):
    """Get an iterator with the paths of the files of interest"""
    return map(
        lambda y: os.path.join(root_dir, y),
        filter(
            # Filter only files whose names match some conditions
            lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[0].startswith('bbb') and os.path.splitext(x)[1] == '.txt',
            next(os.walk(root_dir))[2]
        )
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get the path of the folder with the files of interest
    # Here is the folder with the python script
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    # Compute in parallel the sum for each file
    with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count() - 1) as a:
        file_sums = a.imap_unordered(compute_file_sum, get_filepaths(root_dir))

        # Get the total sum
        total_sum = sum(file_sums)
```